# Add empty header or footer on ListView programmatically

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to add empty header or footer on `ListView` to create a space between top and bottom `ListView`. I could create another empty layout and add into it. But I'm try to find alternative in coding, create for example linear/frame layout with width (`fill_parent`) and height (say, 50dp) and add header into `ListView`.

Comment: is there any reason preventing you to do this xml-side?

Comment: Because i'm using many layouts and i don't want to change each one of them. it's easier to change in code and i have only one class to that affect all layouts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may do it in this way:

```
LinearLayout viewHeader = new LinearLayout(context);
viewHeader.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 50);
viewHeader.setLayoutParams(lp);

yourListView.addHeaderView(viewHeader, null, false);
```

Comment: it's working, but have a bug now, when scroll too fast up and down, the listview is messed up, gone up. i ended up not adding though.