# How to set Header , Scrollable content and Footer? in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, header, android-linearlayout, footer

[image: content]

I want to make middle part to be scrollable. I couldn't get any idea..  and this is my xml outline. I want to insert this xml outline in scrollable area.

Note: Header and Footer has to be constant. Only middle area has to be scrolled

[image: outline]

Answer (score 10):

The easier way is to use :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollablContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footerView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: its just a sample you have to add your widget to the specific groupview, for example your header must be added to the LinearLayout headerView.

Answer (score 3):

You have to replace the external container from LinearLayout to RelativeLayout, then set the alignParentTop=true for the header ImageView, alignParentBottom=true for the footer ImageView,  and set layout_above="@+id/imageViewFooter", layout_below="@+id/imageViewHeader" for the ScrollView. Like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/square" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewFooter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/square" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageViewFooter"

        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewHeader" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How to set this `android:scaleType="fitXY"`and `android:src="@drawable/square"`

Comment: MyBAD!! I got it.. what is meant by fitXY

Comment: fitXY simply tells to the ImageView that the image must be fitted to the imposed dimensions, without respecting the proportions.

Comment: when keyboard pop up footer view also scroll up how to disable

Answer (score 3):

You might want the listView with header and footer in it.

Have you seen [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121186/android-listview-with-header-and-footer-buttons)

Also See [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262704/add-empty-header-or-footer-on-listview-programmatically)

and also [this one.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29)

Hope this all help you. if not then let me know.

Enjoy coding. :)