# My footer comes up when keyboard appears

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I have made a simple footer with some buttons and it shows up quite well but I just have 1 problem that it should not come up when the keyboard is `visible`. It should *remain down* and keyboard must cover it.

Here is my layout file-

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_above="@id/footerView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Name"
                android:id="@+id/textView40"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/ETNameSU"
                android:hint="Daksh Agrawal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/view_books"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/my_profile" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/post_book" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/chat" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/top_donors" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove adjustPan or adjustResize from manifest.

Comment: There is no adjustPan in manifest

Comment: post your entire xml layout

Comment: why are you creating scrollview unwanted. remove it.

Comment: Its all....for it's just a trial app

Comment: it must be relativeLayout as parentlayout right?

Comment: Tried removing.....just the same

Comment: Yes....I saw this question on stack overflow and copied everything [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938092/how-to-set-header-scrollable-content-and-footer-in-android)

Comment: You can use this in your onCreate() in Activity or onCreateView() in fragment         getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

Comment: Pls give the code properly.....it is not accepting getActivity() and LayoutParams.....even there is nothing to import

Comment: Use @AbhishekJaiswal approach  it works

Comment: If you are using your layout in Activity then use this in onCreate                         getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

Comment: @Daksh Agrawal check my answer :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this in your manifest activity**

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="hidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `android:layout_above="@id/footerView"`

Comment: They will start to merge when the layout needs to be scrollable.....my own experience

Answer (score 0):

cross your fingers lets customize it-(Tested and working for me very well!)

In your `OnCreate`  initialize your `rootView`(parent view in your XML) and your `footerView`

call this method from your `OnCreate`- once the keyboard is up `footerView` visibility changes

```
 public void testKeyBoardUp(){
        rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Rect r = new Rect();
                rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                int heightDiff = rel.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);

                if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                    //ok now we know the keyboard is up...
                    footer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                }else{
                    //ok now we know the keyboard is down...
                    footer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope you like it